# CI/CD for new ECS task Definations

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, amazon-ecs, continuous-deployment

I have Jenkins pipeline which builds docker image of spring boot application and push that image to AWS ECR.We have created ECS cluster which takes this image from ECR repository and runs container using ECS task and services.

We have created ECS cluster manually.But now i want whenever a new image is pushed by my CICD to ECR repository it should take the new image and create new task definition and run automatically.What are the ways to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

> But now i want whenever a new image is pushed by my CICD to ECR
>   repository it should take the new image and create new task definition
>   and run automatically.What are the ways to achieve this ?

As far this step is a concern, it would more easy to do with [code pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) as there is no out of the box feature in Jenkins which can detect changes in ECR image.

> The completed **pipeline detects changes to your image**, which is
>   stored in the Amazon ECR image repository, and uses CodeDeploy to
>   route and deploy traffic to an Amazon ECS cluster and load balancer.
>   CodeDeploy uses a listener to reroute traffic to the port of the
>   updated container specified in the AppSpec file. The pipeline is also
>   configured to use a CodeCommit source location where your Amazon ECS
>   task definition is stored. In this tutorial, you configure each of
>   these AWS resources and then create your pipeline with stages that
>   contain actions for each resource.

[image]

[tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy.html)

[build-a-continuous-delivery-pipeline-for-your-container-images-with-amazon-ecr-as-source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/build-a-continuous-delivery-pipeline-for-your-container-images-with-amazon-ecr-as-source/)

If you are looking for this thing in Jenkins, then you have to manage these things at your end.

Here will be the step

- Push image to ECR
- re-use the image name and Create Task definition in your jenkins job [using aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-task-definition.html) or [ecs-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-create.html) with same image name
- [Create service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/create-service.html) with new task definitioni

You can look for details here

[set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-jenkins-and-amazon-ecs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-jenkins-and-amazon-ecs/)

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up to the same conclusion, as there was no exact tooling matching this scenario. So we developed a little "glueing" tool from fee others open-source ones, and recently open-sourced as well:

https://github.com/GuccioGucci/yoke

Please have a look, since we're sharing templates for Jenkins, as it's our pipeline orchestrator as well.